# Retrieve TOP 1 on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

How can I retreive only one entity from a query on Google App Engine. I'm creating a query for with ORDER BY and using:

```
List<Object> objs= (List<Object>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
if (objs.size() > 0) {
    obj= objs.get(0);
}
```

But, when I have a large amount of "Objs" in Database, the query is too expensive, and I'm having too much delay.

There is another way to do this query?

Comment: Why not just call .get() unconditionally, and catch the exception or check for `null` if the object doesn't exist? Calling `size` counts the entire result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this document](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Fetching_Results).

These are valid usages of a query:

```
// Construct then prepare your query
List<Entity> get5TallestPeople() {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Query q = new Query("Person");
    q.addSort("height", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
    return pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));
}
```

and

```
return pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5).offset(5)));
```

In your case I guess you can use the latter syntax.

It uses low level Java API rather than JDO, but it shouldn't put you off from using it.

Comment: And he can use JDO query by setting a range on the query too, achieving the same thing

Comment: Setting a range for a JDO query is done using query.setRange(x, y) method. This is a bit hard to find if you look for limit/cursor. [This](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html#Introducing_Queries) is the link.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using the `fetch` method.. this can give you a similar result as `top 1`

Comment: But how can I use fetch in Java GAE? I saw this API (in documentation) for Python, but not for Java. :(